# GDP for World Powers during the Napoleonic Era?

Tags: economy, napoleonic-wars

What was the GDP for the strongest world Powers during the Napoleonic Era? Powers like United Kingdom, France, Prussia, Russia, Austria, Holland, Spain, Denmark, United States, China, Ottoman Empire and the Maratha Confederacy?

My assumption is that United Kingdom had the largest economy in the world but I like some data to justify this statement.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Wikipedia's [List of regions by past GDP] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_by_past_GDP_(PPP)). Especially the caveat - "In the absence of sufficient data for nearly all economies until well into the 19th century, past GDP cannot be calculated, but at best only roughly estimated"

Answer (score 1):

According to the data from [Maddison](http://www.ggdc.net/maddison/Historical_Statistics/horizontal-file_02-2010.xls) you might make your guess using information from year 1820.

In millions:

United Kingdom: 36,232
France: 35,468
Prussia: 26,819 (surely less, because it covers all present German territory); perhaps half this or a little more.
Russia: 37,678 (probably less, because it covers all former Soviet Union territory)
Austria: My guess is near 20,000 (data shows info from current European countries)
Holland: 4,288
Spain: 12,299
Denmark: 1,471
United States: 13,499
China: 228,600
Ottoman Empire: My guess is close to 14,000
Maratha Confederacy: 111,417 (far less, probably half of this, because it covers probably the whole indian subcontinent)

Comment: There probably was a big difference between the gdp of France in 1800 and the one in 1820

Comment: "Former Soviet Union territory" is less than 1820 Russia territory.

Comment: @kubanczyk: But 1820 Russia includes the *Grand Duchy of Warsaw* territory that was part of Prussia until 1806. In 1815 Prussia traded the *Grand Duchy of Warsaw* territory to Russia in exchange for several small Rhineland states I that had been part of Westphalia, so probably about even; the Polish territory was larger but lower population density and more rural.

Comment: "millions" of what?

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires Maddison likes to use 1990 US dollars (a.k.a. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geary%E2%80%93Khamis_dollar)